# Request.TotalBytes and HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength always zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal

After a major upgrade to an ASP.Net website a bit of old code (paypal IPN) that has not changed in a few years has stopped working

```
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
```

Request.ContentLength is always returning zero, as does Request.TotalBytes.

I assume it is something to do with the upgrade - added MVC to an ASP.Net Website, upgraded to .net 4.5, among other things.  But these changes cannot be easily reversed, even for testing.

What could cause Request.TotalBytes and HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength to always zero?

Comment: Is the HTTP request streaming the body? Does the HTTP request have a Content-Length header?

Comment: Fiddler tells me there is a "Content-Length: 1788" in the headers.  Not sure what you mean about 'streaming the body'

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: how you resolved this issue????